# Matlab - Removing whitespace around a figure produced by a toolbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using a [toolbox](http://tocsy.pik-potsdam.de/CRPtoolbox/) which gives figure as output for a certain command. When I export the image as eps or pdf, there are whitespace around the image. As the toolbox directly produces the image as output, I can not use any of solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801730/get-rid-of-the-white-space-around-matlab-figures-pdf-output). How do I remove the white space from the image?

Comment: the whitespace I assume is the boarder of the figure? You can still use the solution you posted by editing the output section of the toolbox you are using.

Comment: Does the output save a figure or just produce a figure on the screen?

Comment: @Suever: It produces a figure on the screen. I have found a solution, although not in matlab.   " cat image_with_whitespace.eps | ps2eps > image_without_whitespace.eps " This does the job for me.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar With access to the figure you can use [export_fig](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) like I already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891582/how-to-center-matlab-eps-figure-in-latex-document/30891868#30891868)